# How to create a new List<A> from an existing List<B> using lambda without function

Tags: java, lambda

I have an existing List of type "A". I want to create a new list of type "B" from this list. Class "B" shares some common fields with Class "A" as shown in the example below. preferably, I like to avoid using any function calls from the lambda.

```
public class A{
   int quantity;
   String description;
   int refNumber;
   Date timeStamp;
   
}
public class B{
    int quantity;
    String description;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Of course you can, but the lambda may not look very elegant. It's better to have a method that converts an instance of AObject to an instance of BObject (for example, it can be a constructor of class BObject that accepts an AObject argument).

Comment: What exactly do you have written and in what way does this not look good / work / satisfy your needs? Since `AObject` and `BObject` have nothing to do with each other you need to write code to convert between the two and that code needs to put somewhere, in a function or lambda or anonymous class...

Comment: @TonyHimself do you want to do this without calling `map` on a `stream`?

Comment: @TonyHimself you can always do `streamA.map(a -> {BObject b = new BObject(); ...; return b;}).collect(...)`, but it's ugly.

Comment: Thanks Eran, I think I will stick with what I have, which is the stream().map(func) calling a function.

Comment: I believe the question was closed because you state `Currently, I am doing this using lambda and function`, yet you don't show the code you intend to improve.

Comment: Auh, so I now know. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have two solution for you without using `stream.map` but both of them look ugly and I would recommend a proper and clean solution with a `map` function.

```
List<BObject> listB = list.stream().collect(Collectors.mapping(a -> new BObject(a.quantity, a.description), Collectors.toList()));
```

or

```
List<BObject> listB = list.stream().collect(ArrayList::new, (listBa, a) -> listBa.add(new BObject(a.quantity, a.description)), ArrayList::addAll);
```

Now let's compare solutions above to this:

```
List<BObject> listB = list.stream().map(BObject::new).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

or this

```
List<BObject> listB = list.stream().map(a -> new BObject(a.quantity, a.description)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I think the last two versions look much better but require additional constructors in `BObject` class